# Net.Mail.SmtpClient Not sending to external emails

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email

Hey guys i am using a function that will essentially send all emails out to users. However it only emails to users that are on our servers. Anyone that is using @gmail or @hotmail, do not seem to be getting our emails at all. Here is the code. Again this works for my server emails but external emails are not going out.

The website is hosted on our servers.

```
Public Function SendMail(ByVal EmailFrom As String, ByVal EmailTo As String, ByVal EmailBcc As String, ByVal EmailSubject As String, ByVal EmailBody As String, ByVal Attachment As String) As Boolean

    Dim EmailMessage As New Net.Mail.MailMessage
    EmailMessage = New Net.Mail.MailMessage(EmailFrom, EmailTo, EmailSubject, EmailBody)

    If EmailBcc <> "" Then
        EmailMessage.Bcc.Add(EmailBcc)
    End If

    Dim MailClient As New Net.Mail.SmtpClient("exchange1", 25)
    MailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    '        MailClient.EnableSsl = False
    EmailMessage.IsBodyHtml = True

    If Attachment <> "" Then
        Dim EMailAttachment As New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(Attachment)
        EmailMessage.Attachments.Add(EMailAttachment)
    End If

    Try
        MailClient.Send(EmailMessage)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        'MsgBox("Email Error: " & ex.Message)
        '            Return False
    End Try

End Function
```

EDIT: Can anyone explain why emails are sent when i deploy to my webserver, but not when im in my localhost iis?

Comment: It's *highly likely* that this has nothing to do with the code and everything to do with the SMTP server.  You should check your server logs and see what it's doing with those messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than likely your Exchange server is set up to not allow anonymous messages to be sent externally. You'll probably have to authenticate with valid credentials, and ensure that this account has access to send external emails - something your Exchange administrator can do.

Comment: You need to have a your admin create a contact for the outside email. Once that is created you can add the contact to a distribution group to make coding easier.

Comment: Can anyone explain why emails are sent when i deploy to my webserver, but not when im in my localhost iis?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a username and password for the smtp server (or change the smtp server settings to allow email to be sent outside without authentication, which is generally a bad idea).

```
MailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = True
MailClient.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password)
```